# How to get each element inside a map and change its CSS?

Tags: javascript, java, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to loop through and assign a custom CSS property to each element inside a map called "item", but I don't know how to do that. Below is my code:

```
import React from "react";

// Splitting Letters
const SplitText = React.memo(({ str }) => {
  

  const customStyle = {
    position: "absolute",
    /*top: some random top value,*/
    /*left: some random left value,*/
    zIndex: "initial",
    color: "green"
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {str.split("").map((item, index) => {

        
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            {item}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
});

export default SplitText;
```

My "item" has a set of letters and I want to catch hold of each letter and somehow map the customStyle CSS property to it.

Any suggestions would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

return them with your customStyle

```js
  const customStyle = [{
    position: "absolute",
    /*top: some random top value,*/
    /*left: some random left value,*/
    zIndex: "initial",
    color: "green"
  },{
    position: "relative",
    /*top: some random top value,*/
    /*left: some random left value,*/
    zIndex: "1",
    color: "red"
  }];

 return (
          <div key={index} style={customStyle[index]}>
            {item}
          </div>
        );
```

Comment: I have tried that, but it will assign CSS to all of the elements in item. My {item} has a set of letters, so if I do this it will apply same CSS to all the letters. I want to somehow may be loop it and apply CSS to each letter.

Comment: then Make your customStyle to array and match with index, apply CSS to them

Comment: How can I do that... That's the thing I'm trying to know.. how ?

Comment: I editted answer, check this out